# Accessing single SQLite Database from different application (from Native app and Air For Android App)

Tags: android, database, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I've created an Android native application with SQLite database, I've games created in Air For Android using Adobe Flash Professional CS6.
My Database Name is `Demo.db` created by native application within the package `com.mypack.myApp`. and as my the database is stored in `data/data/com.mypack.myApp/databases/Demo.db`. I want to access data from `Demo.db` in my Air for Android App, I don't want to create different database.

In short How can I access single Database from different application, either from native app or from Air app.

How can we do this?

Comment: do you mean sharing the same DB across multiple Android apps? Consider to store in remote server.

Comment: exactly, I want to share the same DB across multiple Android apps, but my apps are offline..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Share Sqlite Between Two Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707731/how-to-share-sqlite-between-two-application)