# Connecting android app to a database in another android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, share

I already following this link [Share SQLite database between 2 android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps)
But I don know where to put this code in the host app

```
DBadapter hostDBAdapter = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
performerDBadapter.open();
```

Anyone know where to put those code?

Comment: use a content provider.

Comment: How to use content provider? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: haven't you read the link you posted? else, just type content provider in basically any search engine, but most specifically in the searchbox of the android developer website, you'll find plenty

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted the wrong link. Here it is the link that I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps