# Dragging and Dropping a SQLite database between projects

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I see a sqllite database in another application, why can't I just just drag and drop from that application to mine in the eclipse environment? that way I can use data already in that database?

Comment: Probably Android OS, Security Protocol.

Comment: This is essentially why they don't allow you to just pull a database in and drop it into the application.

Comment: Design time is about the *Eclipse Environment* (and Eclipse Projects), and has nothing to do with the *Android Runtime* (or Android Applications, excepting as such are split across Eclipse Projects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't do too well with using an sqlite database file directly.  Generally the way to go around it is to package an sqlite database as a resource and on first create of the app to load that resource and then connect to it and then copy all the data out of it.  The downside of this is you are essentially doubling all your data.

If you are the publisher of the other app then you can list the database as a shared database to share between your apps.

[Share SQLite database between 2 android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Noone has written an Eclipse plugin that does that. You can [write one](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=494) if you feel it is both useful and worth your time.