# How to deal with multi accout login in android?

Tags: android

I have several apps which use the same accout. 
The question is when i had more than one apps installed in my phone,how can i login without type username and password if one of the app had logged in.

Answer (score -1):

See below reference code which is having app1 & app2, so using shared preferences suppose you can store username & password in app1 & you can using it in another app2. Here I'm shwing how to access username, you can expand it as per your requirement.

Okay! using this code in Application 1 ( with package name is "com.sharedpref1" ) to store data with Shared Preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", strShareValue);
        editor.commit();
```

And using this code in Application 2 to get data from Shared Preferences in Application 1. We can get it because we use MODE_WORLD_READABLE in application 1:

```
try {
            con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                    "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String data = pref.getString("username", "No Value");
            displaySharedValue.setText(data);

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you could use [Database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for storing username and password, and [share the database among your multiple apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps), settings some field like `is_logged_in` with boolean value `1` when user is loggedin. On app launch, access the database, check for the field `is_logged_in` and display appropriate logged in view.