# Access same SQLite database from 2 apps

Tags: android, sqlite, android-external-storage, android-settings

I want to know if the following is possible. I want to create a new Settings App in Android and then another App as well. I want both to use the same database and I do not want to use a content provider.

So I want to know if it would be possible to do this by storing the database on an external SD card? Are there any risks in doing this and can I access the database on the external storage from the Settings App?

Edit: So the other App that I refer to will query a server and get data that will be used to change settings in Android, but this information will be stored in an SQLite database. Then I want the Settings App to access this information and update the various things, so I need to simply know if both this Settings App and the other application will be able to access the SQLite database on external storage without any problems, so that I can achieve what I require? Hope this is a little more clear?

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: That's a good question but your question is a little general. please be more specific and ask about programming problems. ;)

Comment: I believe this is what you are searching   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps

Comment: @MDMalik yeah I saw that post, just wanted to make sure that this is possible from a Settings App since I have never written one and not sure if there are any limitations etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible

[Share database between two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps/7935032#7935032)

But when the first app has been uninstalled, then the database will be deleted

For sharing database you need to add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:sharedUserId="my.app" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

The database path is private for each application and as far as i know it's not possible to access it directly across applications.

However one approach is that one application makes it's database accessible to the other one using a ContentProvider. Check out if that works for you.

for more read: http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/android-app-components/content-provider