# SQLite database use in different apps

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming.you wanted to know that can an application add or modify database of some other application?

In short can two applications have access to same database in Android?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) is for.  One app can expose an interface to query its own database to another app. You can read all about them [here at the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data can be shared between different applications using [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) like this:

[image]

[image]

If you want to learn further about this, I would recommend you a 1 day course on Content Provider from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud258). You may need to sign in to view the course. It's free.