# How do I share a sqlite database between a Xamarin app and Java Android app

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

As the title says I am wanting to share a Sqlite database between an Android app written in Java and one written in C# using Xamarin. I can successfully share a database between two Java apps ([With the help of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935032/4172545)) but when I try the same thing in Xamarin I am getting the following error:

`Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database`

I think I have two problems.

1. I am not correctly setting the Shared UserId. Currently I am placing the following attribute above my main activity.

   `[Register("my.user.id")]`

   I tried using the `android:sharedUserId="my.user.id"` in the Manifest file but that was throwing errors and wouldn't deploy to my device.
2. I don't know how the whole signing of the app works. So maybe my device sees the two apps as coming from a different publisher for each device and is not allowing the two to share context.

**EDIT :**
Just wanted to add how I signed both applications with the same certificate for future refrence.

The Android cert is noramlly `"C:\Users\userName\.android\debug.keystore"` and the Xamarin cert is noramlly in `"C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"`. I built the Xamarin app first so I copied the debug.keystore file from the xamarin folder to the android one. (I'm sure it would work the other way around but haven't tested it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.Android` does not support `SharedUserId` via an `ApplicationAttribute`. (I guess no one every filed an issue about it)

Ref: [Android.App.ApplicationAttribute](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ApplicationAttribute/)

Add your shared user id via the manifest and it will work fine:

Example:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:sharedUserId="com.sushihangover" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
```

Note: Make sure that you manually uninstall both apps, add the `sharedUserId`, rebuild and reinstall both apps.

Note: Make sure that you are using the same signing certificate for both your Java and Xamarin apps.