# Change the structure of App but maintain the Database with all data

Tags: android, database, android-database

I had loaded my app to play store and now i change the structure of my application.
The old version use simple activity and now the new version is maded like Gmail or play store.

I make a new project with same code and same Database and i would like to know if i load the new apk in the play store the user that update the app can lose the DB data?

How can i make a bakcup of data and restore to the new version of my app?

Comment: Are You using local db(SQLite) ?

Comment: @Dario If you are using SQLite then just increment DATABASE_VERSION by one if there any changes you made in DB else no need.

Comment: yes, sorry i miss the type of DataBase....i use SQLite.... but my problem is that i make a new project with same package of the old project and i would firm it with the same key and load the apk in the old version of project....if it take it like update i think that the DB is the same and the user don't lose data (like a simple app update).... but now i would try to load a new project with same apk.
Anyway i can make a backup to Google Drive and take data back from there?

Comment: And when your DB structure changed then you check difference with this method
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) ;

Comment: @Hayk and if the package is different? the database change or not?

Comment: @Dario If the package is different then app also different, therefore created another DB instance for new package.
Please see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps

Comment: @Hayk thanks for the link....very interesting....so if i create a new project app with same package and i load the apk in the old project and the database structure is the same of the older app, the user don't lose data....
I will try with my phone in local and if i had some problem i write here more detail!