# xamarin.android - how to get access to read and write sqlite db file from shared context?

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I share my .db sqlite file between two aplications.

I succesful shared this file ( because second application can see it ) and just cant use it. I guess that is because of security reasons.

This is how I done sharing:

1. SharedUserId is same for both apps
2. simply creation of database

`var Folder = 
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);`

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Folder, "Paczki.db")))
{
    conn.CreateTable<Odczyt>();
    return true;
};
```

3. Receiving shared context.

`Context sharedContext = null;`

```
try
{
    sharedContext = 
        this.CreatePackageContext(
            "MobilnePaczki.MobilnePaczki", PackageContextFlags.IgnoreSecurity);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
}

using (var conn = 
    new SQLiteConnection(sharedContext.DataDir.ToString() + "/files/Paczki.db")) //I am sure that file exists
//... Could not open database file: ... files/Paczki.db (CannotOpen)
```

What I tried:

1. change `PackageContextFlags.IgnoreSecurity` to `PackageContextFlags.IncludeCode` .. But then `sharedContext = null`
2. Copy .db file to second app and then connect to it, then I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`

From other threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps/7935032#7935032) and  I can see that it is possible to use db file from other application.

Do you have any idea what can i do in such a problem?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Billy's answer I found  out that I declared my SharedUserId in `<application>` tag in `AnfroidManifest.xml`. 
The **correct** way is to declare it in `<manifest>` tag..

`<manifest (...) android:sharedUserId="App.Id">`

After I changed it I got  `INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED` Error when I was installing application. To fix this I used:

`adb shell rm -rf /data/data/appname.appname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, it works. Did you create the database before you set the sharedUserId? When I test this scenario, I meet this problem. If so, uninstall and reinstall the app could solve this problem.

Comment: sharedUserID is declared in the AndroidManifest file, so database is created after setting the sharedUserId.

Comment: did you successfully connect to database in second application (did u try insert or select rows?)

Comment: Yes, I can get data in the second application

Comment: hm.. Could you share somehow your project? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please try [this](https://github.com/Billycool1020/ShareSqlite)

Comment: You are a man Billy! Thank you very very much, I found the problem and described it in UPDATE section.