# Transferring in-app data with and without internet (android)

Tags: android

Is there any simple method to transfer in-app data? My app has a local SQLITE database and I need to allow users to be able to share certain data with or without internet. I'm fairly new to android so I am curious if perhaps there is a library or something for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, others can get access to the data stored in that SQLite database. Here are just a couple of scenarios:

- You store the SQLite database on external storage (e.g. a microSD
  card) and someone gets access to that microSD card. (E.g. you leave
  your phone unattended and someone removes the card.)
- Someone gains physical access to your phone. (E.g. you turn it in
  for repairs without wiping the storage first.)
- You store backups of your phone on your computer and someone gains
  access to those backups.
- You store backups of your phone on an USB key and lose that USB key.
  There is a security bug in Android that allows remote access to the
  phone's storage.
- There is a security bug in the quiz app that allows remote access to
  app's storage.

These are just some of the ways in which someone can get access to that database.

You certainly can share a single database between 2 apps. In order to share data between apps (provided they are issued by the same publisher) you will need to specify a shared user id in the AndroidManifest.xml of both apps

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:sharedUserId="my.app" ... >
```

Comment: This seems all very hardware dependent. Is there any way to do this through software? The data will be app-specific. I was thinking about QR codes but that might be very limiting in size.

Comment: You certainly can share a single database between 2 apps.

In order to share data between apps (provided they are issued by the same publisher) you will need to specify a shared user id in the AndroidManifest.xml of both apps. check out this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps