# answer Access same data from 1 android app to another app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I have 2 apps like facebook and messanger. how i can get the first apps login detail in second app. is there any intent or something to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use [contentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics)

Comment: can you share implementation guide?

Comment: I don't know all the details. Please, check the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RePFTYd7t3w
Room and content provider the sample has a source code https://github.com/delaroy/PersistenceContentProviderSample

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve with sharing of local DB (SQLite) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps) you can check.