# Create a central sqflite database for many apps

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have searched but in vain for an answer to the question: Using sqflite and Flutter is it possible to create a central database which can be accessed by several different Flutter apps?  Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Android, it is possible with a configuration in the manifest.
[Share SQLite database between 2 android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps/7935032#7935032)

But in iOS, every app runs in a sandbox. Then, the same code won't run in both platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, Using `app group`, and you can access shared space with

`-[NSFileManagre containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:]` ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84189?answerId=251851022#251851022))

you can put your sqflite in that path.

[image]